# How to perform statistical test for enrichment of gene lists?

Tags: r, statistical-significance, interpretation, biostatistics, fishers-exact-test

In a typical ChIP-Seq experiment, we found a transcription factor `ABC` peaks on 590 genes. 242 genes out of the 590 genes are classified as `ORF`s. If the number of `ORF`s contained in the genome is 5420, and the total number of genes in the genome is 6226, are the total `ABC` bound genes enriched in `ORF`s? Can we test whether `ABC` association with ORFs is by chance? Which statistical test should be used? Can it be done in R, and if so, how? Is there any other way to do this?

I got to know from this forum that tests for enrichment of gene lists include a hypergeometric test or a one-sided Fisher's exact test. Though I am not very familiar with R, based on other examples, I tried to use R for Fisher's exact test for count data, and my output is this:

```
fisher.test(matrix(c(242,5178,348,458),nrow=2,ncol=2),alternative="greater")

 Fisher's Exact Test for Count Data

data:  matrix(c(242, 5178, 348, 458), nrow = 2, ncol = 2)

p-value = 1

alternative hypothesis: true odds ratio is greater than 1

95 percent confidence interval:
 0.05224986        Inf

sample estimates:

odds ratio
0.06156519
```

My analysis, if correct, suggests that factor `ABC` is related to `ORF`s only by chance. Is this conclusion right? If not, what should be the conclusion?